# PHP 7.2 to php 7.3 (7.4) upgrade carbon timezone change

Tags: php, timezone, php-carbon

With Carbon "2.38.0", I run this code

```
    $now = Carbon::create(2019, 3, 30, 0, 0, 0, 'UTC');
    $now->setTimezone('ACST');
    echo $now->toDateTimeString();
```

When I use PHP 7.2.33, I'm getting

> 2019-03-30 09:00:00

with PHP 7.3.21 (or PHP 7.4.9), I'm getting this

> 2019-03-30 09:30:00

I'm testing it on the same server `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS` changing PHP with

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php ...
```

Why the date conversion depend on PHP version? How can I synchronise them?

Comment: There was a change in 2015: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia#History. Your old PHP may be using an old timezone database…?

Comment: I'm using version `7.3.21` and I'm getting `2019-03-30 09:00:00`, I can't reproduce.

Comment: I'm testing it on the same server `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`  with just `sudo update-alternatives --set php ...`